# jQuery form validation using Telerik (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I really tired of trying to validate a form using jQuery on ASP.NET MVC using Telerik.

i tried everything ..... and i don't understand what I did wrong.

I tried the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery validators but it still doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#customerForm").validate({

        rules: {
        CustomerEnShortName:"required"
    },
    messages: {

        CustomerEnShortName: "<li>Please enter a name.</li>"
    }

});


});
```

The Telerik MVC code:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","Customer", FormMethod.Post, new{ id= "customerForm"})) { %>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary() %>
    <fieldset>


 <legend>CustomerInfo</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <label id="lblCustomerShortName">Customer Short Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
       <%: Html.Telerik().AutoCompleteFor(m =>m.CustomerEnShortName) %>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <label id="lblCustomerFullName" >Customer Full Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
       <%: Html.Telerik().AutoCompleteFor(m => m.CustomerEnFullName) %>
    </div>



    <div class="editor-label">
               <label id="lblCustomerNIN">Customer NIN</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%:Html.Telerik().AutoCompleteFor(m => m.Customer_NIN) %>
    </div>





    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.Label("Is Active") %>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
    <% 
        string isActive;
        if (Model.CustomerActivity == 1)
            isActive = "true";
        else
            isActive = "false";
            %>
      <input id="IsActive" name="IsActive" type="checkbox" checked="<%= isActive %>"  />
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
<%} %>
```

The generated output code is:

```
<form action="/Customer/Edit/31" id="customerForm" method="post">
<div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul><li style="display:none"></li>
  </ul></div>
  <fieldset>
            <legend>CustomerInfo</legend>


        <div class="editor-label">
        <label id="lblCustomerShortName">Customer Short Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
       <input class="t-widget t-autocomplete t-input" id="CustomerEnShortName" name="CustomerEnShortName" type="text" />
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <label id="lblCustomerFullName" >Customer Full Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
       <input class="t-widget t-autocomplete t-input" id="CustomerEnFullName" name="CustomerEnFullName" type="text" value="CUSTOMER -31" />
    </div>        

    <div class="editor-label">
               <label id="lblCustomerNIN">Customer NIN</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="t-widget t-autocomplete t-input" id="Customer_NIN" name="Customer_NIN" type="text" value="1559446285" />
    </div>





    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="Is_Active">Is Active</label>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">

      <input id="IsActive" name="IsActive" type="checkbox" checked="true"  />
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: If you remove the telerik controls, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem in the new release which causes the `jquery.validate` file to be included from the ScriptRegistrar even if specified to be omitted.

It is possible that this is causing your validation to fail.

Try using [this hotfix](http://www.telerik.com/agile-project-management-tools/ClientsFiles/337591_Telerik-Extensions-for-ASPNET-MVC-2012-1-222-hotfix.zip) to resolve the issue.